# Apply Process Function to Groups in a Dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I've got a dataframe, like this:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'X' : ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B'],
                     'Y' : [1,   0,  1,  1,  0,  0,'Nan']})
```

I would like to group it by X and create a column Z:

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'X' : ['A','B'],
                     'Z' : [0.5, 0.5]})
```

But the difficult to describe thing that I would like to do is to apply this function:

```
def fun(Y,Z):
    if Y == 1:
        Z = Z + 1
    elif Y == 0:
        Z = Z - 1
```

So the first Y in df_1 is a 1, that is in group A so the Z for group A increases to 1.5. Then the next one is a 0 so it goes back to 0.5, then there are 2 more 1's so it ends up at 2.5.

Which would give me:

```
X   Z
A   2.5
B   -1.5
```

Comment: What should be done with `NaN`?

Comment: It stays unchanged when there's a NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your first DataFrame and use `sum` with index alignment.

- `0 -> -1` (subtract 1 when a zero is found)
- `NaN --> 0` (unchanged when a `NaN` is found

---

```
df_1['Y'] = pd.to_numeric(df_1.Y, errors='coerce')

u = df_1.assign(Z=df_1.Y.replace({0: -1, np.nan: 0})).groupby('X')['Z'].sum().to_frame()

df_2 = df_2.set_index('X') + u
```

```
     Z
X
A  2.5
B -1.5
```

Comment: If your `Y` isn't numeric, you need to do `df_1.Y = pd.to_numeric(df_1.Y)`

Comment: Sorry, you need to use `pd.to_numeric(df_1.Y, errors='coerce')`